# EOF Error when reading from stdin (python3)

Tags: python, list

The following user inputs are read from stdin, **line by line**, and then each line may be several numbers separated by space:

```
3
2 1
1 1 0
```

After each line is entered the value must be stored in a list:

```
examList = [
      [3],
      [2,1],
      [1,1,0]
]
```

Using the following code I am unable to add all of the values to the list due to

```
EOFError: EOF when reading line
```

when reading the last line of input and I am not aware why. This error occurs even when a single int is inputted. Is there any other way to determine the EOF for user input?

The code must be able to run in online practice IDE's such as those on HackerRank or LeetCode.

```
examList = []
i = input()
while i != '':
    examList.append([int(s) for s in i.split()])
    i = input()
    print(examList) 
print (examList)
```

Console after running the code and input above:

```
Error: 

[[3]]
[[3], [2,1]]
Line 5: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? The first `input` or the second?

Comment: @LeviLesches The error occurs when reading the last input. So for the example above, _examList_ reads all of the proceeding inputs but throws the error when trying to read _1 1 0_

Comment: So, it can read "2 1" but not "1 1 0"? Also, what line of code throws the error? Just trying to understand.

Comment: @LeviLesches yes, that is correct. Line 5 throws the error when it tries to read "1 1 0"

Comment: Ensure that there are no typos in your code, because I copied and pasted it, and it ran totally fine. @DyZ I even typed in exactly what is written on top and it worked

Comment: It could also be the IDE you're using

Comment: @LeviLesches  I copied and pasted my exact code aswell as changed the print location/added the exact error log to show how my program executes.

Comment: Hm, sorry. My version of your code works perfectly, the only difference I see is in your IDE, which must be the issue. I even tried adding weird whitespace to trick it but it still worked. Try running the code on a local version of python